# Adding close button in div to close the box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a URL preview box for the entered URL.

Preview is shown in the div box. I want to add a close option on the right top.
How could be done so that when users click on its box should be disabled?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/xftr5/).

```
<a class="fragment" href="google.com">
    <div>
    <img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
    <h3>the title will go here</h3>
        <h4> www.myurlwill.com </h4>
    <p class="text">
        this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
    </p>
</div>
</a>
```

**code** is inside `php`

Comment: Disable or hide the box?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A simple close button:

```html
<span id="close" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.remove(); return false;">x</span>
```

Add this inside your `div`:

```css
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #369;
}
.fragment h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
#close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<br /><br />
<a class="fragment" href="google.com">
    <div>
        <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.remove(); return false;'>x</span>
        <img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
        <h3>the title will go here</h3>
        <h4> www.myurlwill.com </h4>
        <p class="text">
            this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

You may also use something like this

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
        return false;
    };
};
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = () => {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
        return false;
    };
};
```

```css
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #369;
}
.fragment h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
#close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<br /><br />
<a class="fragment" href="google.com">
    <div>
        <span id='close'>x</span>
        <img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
        <h3>the title will go here</h3>
        <h4> www.myurlwill.com </h4>
        <p class="text">
            this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

### Styling

Css for close button

```
#close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

You may add a hover effect like

```
#close:hover {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
        return false;
    };
};
```

```css
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #369;
}
.fragment h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
#close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}

#close:hover {
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<br /><br />
<a class="fragment" href="google.com">
    <div>
        <span id='close'>x</span>
        <img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
        <h3>the title will go here</h3>
        <h4> www.myurlwill.com </h4>
        <p class="text">
            this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: the first suggestion makes all the page blank after clicked

Comment: why three times parentNode? It worked. But i don't understand how?

Comment: Because,  the element is nested in three parent nodes.

Answer (score 11):

it's easy with the id of the div container : (I didn't put the close button inside the `<a>` because that's does work properly on all browser.

```
<div id="myDiv">
<button class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display='none'" >Close</button>
<a class="fragment" href="http://google.com">
    <div>
    <img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
    <h3>the title will go here</h3>
        <h4> www.myurlwill.com </h4>
    <p class="text">
        this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
    </p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xftr5/12/)

And **HTML**:

```
<div id="previewBox">
    <button id="closeButton">Close</button>
<a class="fragment" href="google.com">
    <div>
    <img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
    <h3>the title will go here</h3>
        <h4> www.myurlwill.com </h4>
    <p class="text">
        this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
    </p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

With **JS (jquery required)**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#closeButton').on('click', function(e) { 
        $('#previewBox').remove(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I used this on a cart page but I'm noticing that the buttons don't work if the cart contents are updated, something is removed, etc., after the cart updates with JS. I'm not entirely certain what, if anything, I should do to fix the issue given the possibility of JS conflicts with the eCommerce system. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

A jQuery solution: Add this button inside any element you want to be able to close:

```
<button type='button' class='close' onclick='$(this).parent().remove();'>×</button>
```

or to 'just' hide it:

```
<button type='button' class='close' onclick='$(this).parent().hide();'>×</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xftr5/15/)**

Your **HTML** should look like this (I only added the button):

```
<a class="fragment" href="google.com">
    <button id="closeButton">close</button>
    <div>
        <img src ="http://placehold.it/116x116" alt="some description"/> 
        <h3>the title will go here</h3>
        <h4> www.myurlwill.com </h4>
        <p class="text">
        this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etc this is a short description yada yada peanuts etcthis is a short description yada yada peanuts etc 
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

and you should add the following **CSS**:

```
.fragment {
    position: relative;
}
#closeButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Then, to make the button actually work, you should add this javascript:

```
document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

We're using `e.preventDefault()` here to prevent the anchor from following the link.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xftr5/11/
Hope, everything is clear?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fragment i').on('click', function(e) { $(e.target).closest('a').remove(); });
});
```

Added jQuery and inserted an `<i>` as close trigger...

Comment: the code is probably correct but I'm not sure jquery is available

Answer (score 1):

jQuery("#your_div_id").remove(); will completely remove the corresponding elements from the HTML DOM. So if you want to show the div on another event without a refresh, it will not be possible to retrieve the removed elements back unless you use AJAX.

jQuery("#your_div_id").toggle("slow"); will also could make unexpected results. As an Example when you select some element on your div which generates another div with a close button(which uses the same close functionality just as your previous div) it could make undesired behaviour.

So without using AJAX, a good solution for the close button would be as follows

HTML____________

```
<div id="your_div_id">
<span class="close_div" onclick="close_div(1)">&#10006</span>
</div>
```

JQUERY__________

```
function close_div(id) {
    if(id === 1) {
        jQuery("#your_div_id").hide();
    }
}
```

Now you can show the div, when another event occures as you wish... :-)

Comment: Doesn't it make much more sense to - instead of calling some function and introducing all kinds of extra ID's - to use onclick='$(this).parent().hide()' or onclick='$(this).parent().remove()'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. The goal was to create a button (on clicking lets say another button/entity), AND add a remove mechanics to it. I added the following script to the javascript file-

```
        let newbtn = document.createElement("button");
        newbtn.innerHTML = 'whatever text you want the button to have';


       // the remove button
       let xspan = document.createElement('span');
       xspan.innerHTML = '<sup>X</sup>'; //this gives it superscript text
       xspan.id = 'close'; //this was not necessary but it is nice to have
       xspan.onclick = function () {
         newbtn.remove();
       };
       newbtn.appendChild(xspan);
```

This worked for me. I realize that the superscript could be substituted with more code that would perhaps give it more substance but the goal here is to give it an X to click on.