# Closable <div> not working on Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am implementing a closable `<div>` using pure CSS and not Javascript.

**HTML and CSS:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<style>
  div.messages 
  {
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: #bce8a1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 300px;
  }

  div.messages:before
  {
    content: "\274C";
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  div.messages:active
  {
    height: 0px;
    display: none;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class= "messages">
      In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a filler text commonly used to demonstrate the graphic elements of a document or visual presentation. Replacing meaningful content that could be distracting with placeholder text may allow viewers to focus on graphic aspects such as font, typography, and page layout. It also reduces the need for the designer to come up with meaningful text, as they can instead use hastily generated lorem ipsum text.
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code works (sort of) but am having a few notes that I would like to ask for help with

1. The close works OK on Firefox; Chrome appears to close also but the `<div>` reappears as soon as the mouse is released
2. The `<div>` blinks whenever I click anywhere within its bounds. How do I make it remain showing?

Comment: `reappears as soon as the mouse is released` is what behavior of `:active`

Comment: did you reviewed this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704477/adding-close-button-in-div-to-close-the-box ?

Comment: Permanently changing the state of an object `onclick` isn't possible with CSS. Active is really only useful if you want something to happen when the mouse button is being held down.

Comment: Does this mean I must use Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using :active to modify your div. Active is a css word reserved for mouse events on an element. I have myself never found need to use :active on a div. (In essence I use them for clickable objects ie. anchors, buttons). Now :active is also only applied when click is happening.

You'll notice clicking in the center of the div will also mike it shrink to `height: 0px`.

Solution:

-The proper solution would use js, toggled by a button, to apply a class to the div you want to shrink. The class will have `height: 0; display:none;`

-You could hack this using anchor with :active. But this is bad practice.(I will update with this when I get the chance)