# Need to click 2 times to close a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and I want close it when it popup. I am referring  similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19704740). Only change is I gave `span` instead of button. Now my problem is I need to click 2 times on close symbol to close the `div`.

My code

```
contactResault.html("
  <div id='hidediv' style='text-align:left'>
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>
      x
    </span>
    <h5 style='color:black;background-color:white!important;'>
      Thank you for Subscribing!
    </h5>
    <br/>
    <span style='color:black;background-color:white!important;'>
      Thank you for your interest in joining IEP|ONE, The Cognitive Companion for Children with Special Needs beta users group.
    </span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span style='color:black;background-color:white!important;'> We will send you the link to download our Companion App from Apple and Google store as soon as it is available.
    </span>
    <br/>
    </br>
    <span style='color:black;background-color:white!important;'>Thank you!</span></br><span style='color:black;background-color:white!important;'>IEP|ONE Beta Users Team
    </span>
  </div>
");
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

and css

```
#close {
 float:right;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:2px 5px;
 background:#ccc;  
}

#close:hover {
 float:right;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:2px 5px;
 background:#ccc;
 color:#fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: It gets removed the first time for me: https://jsfiddle.net/j2p6rje8/ (but you should attach all your listeners in Javascript, not in HTML attributes - that's as bad as `eval`) Spelling matters too, you might want to check `contactResault`

Comment: why did you give click event in both html and javascript?

Comment: Are you purposely rendering your HTML using JavaScript?

Comment: Also, i created a CodePen to replicate the problem. I only had to click once and things looked fine. Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/DaneTheory/pen/qYRmxJ

Comment: Thank you for commenting guys, I checked in your code pen ,if I remove   onclick from html it works fine in codepen,but in my code it will not work

Comment: sorry..It is taking from html code only..It is not taking if I write javascript or jquery outside. How to make it work. I need to write html code inside js , I can not change that. But It is not taking any javascript function based on id or class

Comment: currently my html code is in js and this html code is not taking any js function.for example based on id I can not perform any action